# ResultSet.previous not working

Tags: java, jdbc

it seems I can't get to scroll through my `ResultSet` the way I want :

```
public void getCurves(String runId, File file, Connection conn) {
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(CDS, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE);
        int k = ps.getResultSetType();
        ps.setString(1, runId);
        ps.setFetchSize(1500);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();

        ccw.writeCore(file, rs);
        ccw.writeFooter(file, "value;data");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        close(rs, ps);
    }
}
```

Here, even though I set the `ResultSet.type` to `ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE` which is a constant worth 1004, `k` is worth 1003, which is equivalent to `ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`.

Am I setting this wrongly ?

**EDIT** : I am using oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

Comment: Depends on the driver, not all drivers support scrollable result sets.

Comment: How do I know which driver I am using ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't set ResultSet type , so you left it to its default value, which is : `ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`.  Here is your method API  : [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement(java.lang.String,int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement%28java.lang.String,int%29)

You must use:

```
prepareStatement(sql, resultSetType, resultSetConcurrency);
```

OR

```
prepareStatement(sql, resultSetType, resultSetConcurrency, resultSetHoldability);
```

So for you , this should be enough:

```
conn.prepareStatement(CDS, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
```